# Bootstrap alert not closing on clicking the X button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and my alert element is not closing when the x button is clicked.

```
<div runat ="server" class="alert alert-error modalEditError"  
    id="modalEditError" 
    visible ="false">
    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modalEditError">×</button>
    <strong>The updated interview information was not saved!</strong>
    <div id="Div2" runat="server"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The CSS class 'modalEditError' doesn't really exist; that was me trying to get the thing to close in case the mechanism functions on class names and not id value.

Comment: And are you including the `alert.js` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the `alert-dismissible` class, and your `data-dismiss` on the button should target `alert`:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" runat ="server" id="modalEditError" visible ="false">
  <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  <strong>The updated interview information was not saved!</strong> <div id="Div2" runat="server" ></div>
</div>
```

Also note, `alert-error` isn't a bootstrap class, but `alert-danger` (red) is.

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/VL8Wyfea7A)

[Bootstrap Alert Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)

Comment: can i call it something other than 'alert'  for dismissal? because io have a function to auto close them in 3 seconds: function myTimer() {
            $("#MyPageAlert").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow", function () { $(this).remove(); });
        }

Comment: my id in my timeout didn't match my alert tag's id. works like a charm

Comment: Yeah, the above `data-dismiss` is only used for closing the alert when the `X` button is clicked. Using `$("#modalEditError").modal("hide");` inside that timeout function would accomplish the same as your `.delay(...)` function. Glad this helped though.